# How to make a spinner with a message with i18n?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, interceptor, angular-i18n

So I am using angular material and I have a spinner that works smoothly.

But now I have also translations with i18. And I want besides having a spinner on each http request, also showing a specific message under the spinner.

So I have a loaderServce:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {
  loaderState = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  show() {
    this.loaderState.next(true);
  }

  hide() {
    this.loaderState.next(false);
  }
}
```

and the interceptor:

```
export class LoaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {


constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.showLoader();

    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.onEnd();
      }
    },
      (err: any) => {
        this.onEnd();
      }));

  }

  private onEnd(): void {
    this.hideLoader();
  }

  private showLoader(): void {
    this.loaderService.show();
  }

  private hideLoader(): void {
    this.loaderService.hide();
  }

}
```

and then the actual component where the spinner will be shown:

```
<app-loader></app-loader>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="saveAndPublish()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save & Publish</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button>
<form [formGroup]="form"  >
  <app-node-tree-input formControlName="nodes"></app-node-tree-input>
</form>
```

and ts code:

```
save() {

    const model = this.getSubmitModel();

    if (model) {
        this.schemaTemplateService.createVersion(model.name, model)
      .subscribe((schema) => {
        this.i18n('Saving & Publishing...');
        console.log('schema', schema);
        // TODO feedback
      });
    }
  }
```

But the message is not shown this way.

So my question is: how to show the translated message?

Thank you

so if I do this:

```
save() {

    const model = this.getSubmitModel();

    if (model) {
        this.schemaTemplateService.createVersion(model.name, model)
      .subscribe((schema) => {
      console.log(this.i18n('Saving & Publishing...'));
        console.log('schema', schema);
        // TODO feedback
      });
    }
  }
```

I see the console message:

```
 console.log(this.i18n('Saving & Publishing...'));
```

but it is not shown on the template(html)

Comment: can you put your code on `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular` or `CodeSandbox `

Comment: What do you mean? I have put all the code here.

Comment: like this way im sharing my project `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csykwa`